# Python PDM package manager: How to enable virtual environment autodetection?

Tags: python, python-pdm

Python PDM Project

https://pdm.fming.dev/latest/

https://github.com/pdm-project/pdm

My Problem

In context below I want to activate the in-project virtual environment automatically whenever the directory changes to inclued the path `~/pydev/pdm-test`.

Tree View of PDM Test Folder

```
$ tree ~/pydev/pdm-test -aL 2
/home/joe/pydev/pdm-test
├── 0000-proj0000
│   ├── main.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── 0005-proj0005
├── 0010-proj0010
├── pdm.lock
├── .pdm.toml
├── pyproject.toml
└── .venv
    ├── bin
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── lib
    └── pyvenv.cfg
```

Manual Activation of Virtual Environment (this works)

`$ eval $(pdm venv activate in-project)`

Virtual Environment Autodetection

https://pdm.fming.dev/latest/usage/venv/

> When no interpreter is stored in the project config or PDM_IGNORE_SAVED_PYTHON env var is set, PDM will try to detect possible virtualenvs to use:
>
> - venv, env, .venv directories in the project root
> - The currently activated virtualenv

Question - Where is the "project config" file and how do I edit this file or use a pdm command to enable virtual environment autodetection?

Answer (score 0):

The python path is stored in the project config file `.pdm.toml`, view it and remove the corresponding line to clear the python path. You can also do it with command line: `pdm config -ld python.path`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a straight forward way to auto-activate the venv in the current shell.

> Where is the "project config" file

.pdm-python
Inside the project root

> how do I edit this file or use a pdm command to enable virtual
> environment autodetection?

auto-detection works by default, what is meant by auto-detection is that if you run any pdm command, it will use that venv, which is normally .venv in the project root, auto-activation is a different topic.

**Update:** Auto-Activation
in ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc

```bash
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@"
    # bash regex pdm-test / conditionally activate the venv in the current shell
    if [[ "$PWD" =~ pdm-test ]]
    then
        eval $(pdm venv activate)
    fi
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried ```PDM``` briefly ... then moved on ... because I could not see any advantages. On Debian-based host systems I now install python to each project folder using ```pyenv``` and ```direnv```. This provides isolation and seems to use less disk space in my use cases.